# Can't set permissions on AWS Secrets Manager

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

I'm trying to set resource permissions to get secret value on Amazon's secrets manager from a lambda function. I keep getting this -rather poor- error message:

> This resource policy contains a syntax error.

I already tried checking the version key, which I took directly from the pre-made code, and double checked [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_statement.html) as well.

But I haven't been able to figure out what's going on.

This is my JSON:

```
{
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Actions": ["secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sts::<SOME_ID>:assumed-role/<MY_LAMBDA_NAME>-lambdaRole/<MY_LAMBDA_NAME>-<MY_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME>",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

And for some reason, this is my code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const region = 'us-east-1';
const SecretId = process.env.SECRETS_MANAGER_ARN;

const getSecret = () => {
    let secret, decodedBinarySecret;

    // Create a Secrets Manager client
    const client = new AWS.SecretsManager({
        region: region
    });

    client.getSecretValue({ SecretId }, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            throw err;
        } else {
            // Decrypts secret using the associated KMS CMK.
            // Depending on whether the secret is a string or binary, one of these fields will be populated.
            if ('SecretString' in data) {
                secret = data.SecretString;
                console.log('secret ', secret);
            } else {
                const buff = new Buffer(data.SecretBinary, 'base64');
                decodedBinarySecret = buff.toString('ascii');
                console.log('decodedBinarySecret ', decodedBinarySecret);
            }
            return { secret, decodedBinarySecret };
        }
    });
};

module.exports = {
    getSecret
};
```

Comment: Why do you set a resource policy instead of an IAM role policy?

Answer (score 1):

Try including the "Principal" property

```
{
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Actions": ["secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sts::<SOME_ID>:assumed-role/<MY_LAMBDA_NAME>-lambdaRole/<MY_LAMBDA_NAME>-<MY_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME>",
            "Effect": "Allow"
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

Edit: I'm not sure exactly why this fixes the issue but it seemed to be the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

`arn:aws:sts::<SOME_ID>:assumed-role/<MY_LAMBDA_NAME>-lambdaRole/<MY_LAMBDA_NAME>-<MY_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME>` is not a valid Secret arn.

The resource listed in your policy is an STS assumed-role. The resource should be `arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:<YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID>:secret:<YOUR_SECRET_ID>`